# In an Edit control, how to show translucent text that disappears when new text is entered?

Tags: delphi-7, edit

I made the following code but something does not work.

```
unit Unit9;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, DB, ADODB, Grids, DBGrids, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
    edt1: TEdit; 
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);        
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

const
  EM_SETCUEBANNER = $1501;

implementation

uses
  Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm9.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Banner: String;
  buf: array [0..$ff] of Char;
begin
  Banner := UTF8Encode('Введите логин');
  Utf8ToUnicode(PWideChar(@buf), PAnsiChar(Banner), Length(Banner));
  SendMessage(edt1.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, Integer(@buf));
end;

end.
```

For example, as on some websites, an edit control displays "Login" until something is written.

[image]

Comment: `EM_SETCUEBANNER` works only when an app uses ComCtl32.dll to [enable Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cookbook-overview). Delphi 7 predates the VCL's built-in support for Visual Styles. So you have to manually create the necessary manifest to enable ComCtl32.dll and link it into your app. Are you doing that?

Comment: Even if you do, the VCL in Delphi 7 has many bugs that only appear when Visual Styles are enabled. So you need to add [Soft-Gem's XP Theme Manager](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager) component to your app to correct many of them.

Comment: Also, `Char` is `AnsiChar` in Delphi 7, but `EM_SETCUEBANNER` requires a Unicode string, so `buf` should be using `WideChar` instead of `Char` (which then eliminates the need for the erroneous typecast you are doing when calling `Utf8ToUnicode()`). But you can get rid of `buf`, `UTF8Encode()`, and `Utf8ToUnicode()` if you use `WideString` instead: `var Banner: WideString; Banner := 'Введите логин'; SendMessage(..., Integer(PWideChar(Banner)));`